# Unable to push docker image into docker hub?

Tags: docker

I am trying to push docker image into docker hub, but i am not able to push docker image into docker hub.

[image]

Comment: what errors are you getting? can you show your work?

Comment: You can only push images to registry you own. Do a login via `docker login` at first.

Comment: What command are you typing?  What error are you getting?  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], including any relevant application source code?  I can't read the image you've posted and in general you should never post screenshots of terminal windows into SO questions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to push in the following manner (ensure you are logged into docker on the command line)

```
docker push <dockerusername>/test-img:<tag>
```

Make sure you also build your image as:

```
docker build -t <dockerusername>/test-img <Dockerfile>
```

Comment: Thank You!, I did docker logout and again login , its working